# Android Gallery View, Button in unfocused items goes to selected state

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-gui

I have a gallery view in which i have plugged LinearLayouts by using Custom Adapter. This works fine. But when i scroll (swipe in gallery) between items in gallery, the button on unfocused item is in clicked state. It comes back to its normal state when in focus.

Please guide me how can i fix it. Thanks!

Comment: are you using a custom selector for your button?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Comment: i cant see anything promising here.